# What is the meaning of pwd|sed -e?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting

I found the below snippet at the .sh file of my project to define some path :

```
PGMPATH=`pwd|sed -e "s#/survey1##" `
```

What does the above line means ?

Reference of PGMPATH is used as below :

```
 LIBS="${LIBS}:${PGMPATH}/edmz-par-api_1.4.jar"
 LIBS="${LIBS}:${PGMPATH}/commons-logging.jar"
```

If it is telling the path where the jar file is located , please explain how it works .

Comment: do you know what the `pwd` command does? do you know what `sed` does? these are fairly basic linux commands.

Comment: Have you checked out the man pages?

Comment: Guys , instead of demotivating , please try to help , am new to Linux environment , Any way thanks for your response

Comment: These are basic things. First try to see man page of these commnads. man sed. you will be getting it

Comment: @Esh Stack Overflow requires some effort to solve your problem yourself before posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you should know that this is two commands - `pwd` and `sed -e "s#/survey1##"` - and these two commands are being run together in a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29). That is, the output of the first command is being sent to the second command as input.

That is, in general, what `|` means in unix shell scripts.

So then, what do each of these commands do? `pwd` stands for "print working directory" and prints the current directory (where you ran the script from, unless the script itself had any `cd` commands in it).

`sed` is a command that's really a whole separate programming language that people do many simple text-processing commands with.  The simple `sed` program you have here - `s#/survey1##` - strips the string `/survey1` out of its input, and prints the result.

So the end result is that the variable `PGMPATH` becomes the current directory with `/survey1` stripped out of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel , that helped me understanding my doubt.